# Direct - Indirect speech construction

Tags: reported-speech

1. Father said to me,"Don't sleep at late and miss the train".

A. Father forbade me to sleep late lest I should miss the train.

B. Father asked me not to sleep at late and miss the train.

C. Father advised me not to sleep at late and miss the train.

Foe me, A and C could be possible answer. But A is given in answer sheet.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A is grammatically correct but unbelievably old-fashioned. I learnt the English word "lest" over 50 years ago as a translation of the Latin word "ne" - and it was old-fashoined then. 'Forbade' is rarely heard nowadays.
The word "at" in 1. B. and C. is wrong. Leaving that aside, whether Father is forbidding, asking or advising cannot be deduced from the word "said" and depends on the sort of relationship the child has with the father and on the tone of voice used. I would guess "advised" is the most likely.

Comment: +1 How 'bout just "told"?

Comment: @StoneyB good answer!

Comment: Sir you mentioned that the word "at" is wrong here, but this is part of question also. Do you think it totally incorrect both in question and answers?

Comment: It is certainly wrong in British English."At late" is a construction I have never seen before.

Comment: Definitely ungrammatical in American English too! As @StoneyB said, the most idiomatic way to say this with indirect speech would be "Father told [or warned] me not to sleep late and miss the train." None of "asked," "forbade," or "advised" sound natural to me in this context.